# Jenkins - get EnvInject Plugin info by rest api

Tags: rest, jenkins

I am using https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin 1.93.1 in my Jenkins installation.

I need to fetch the EnvInject properties configuration for every job I have, but I can't seem to find a way to do this in the job rest api.

The way I figured to do this is by fetching the last build for every job and then hit the injectedEnvVars/api/.

This strategy is not optimal because I have to do a request for every job, and that is taking too long (4000+ jobs).

Am I missing something? Is there a way to fetch the envInject properties together with the job information?

Comment: Can you have access to login the Jenkins Master machine, check the JENKINS_HOME folder,  I think there is something to store the EnvInject  value for each job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think send 4000 HTTP requests is not effective, You can iterate the JENKINS_HOME folder on Jenkins Master.

Following picture illustrate the structure for `injectedEnvVars.txt` which stores the value of EnvInject.

1. `.jenkins` is JENKINS_HOME folder
2. `fetch-envinject-value` is jenkins job
3. `builds/1` is the 1st job build
4. `builds/1/injectedEnvVars.txt` is all environment variables for this job build.

[image]

Comment: I figured out why the requests are slow. It has something to do with our LDAP authentication. Each basic auth request takes ~5 seconds vs 100 miliseconds when accessing via browser.